# How to format DataGrid rows based on data's units

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid with a collection of parameters, each of which have properties for name and a value. Each parameters' value can be one of a multitude of units (ft, btuh, kw, currency, string, unit less double, etc.) How do I format the data grid rows to display the value with the units and a unit dependent rounding factor? See below for an example.

[image: Example DataGrid]

The DataGrid can reference different object classes with different collections of parameters so the solution has to be dynamic. Maybe add a `Units` enum to the parameter class and then somehow read that from the DataGrid and format the row accordingly?

Comment: Try to use IValueConverter, you can format the output string as you want in the back code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I would take would be make a converter. I've made you one just to pitch the idea but you should probably modify it to suit your needs.

```
public class CellUnitConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Checks both if the value is null or if the converter somehow gets used ahead of time
        if (value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // You can place some rounding rules here

        return $"{value} {Unit}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As it uses the `MarkupExtension`, you can just place it in the binding of the cell

```
Binding="{Binding Results, Converter={converters:CellUnitConverter Unit=CFM}}"
```

However, if you want different units depending on the value, you could also **Bind** the unit to another property such of each element.

Let's you are displaying a collection of `DataItem` where each one has a `Title`, `Result`,`Unit`. Then, you bind one column to the `Title` and the other one to the `Result`, such like

```
Binding="{Binding Result, Converter={converters:CellUnitConverter Unit={Binding Unit}}}"
```

Hope this points to the solution.